# PostgreSQL table partitioning problem

Tags: postgresql

I partitioned my table  day by day. The child tables are look like points_20150830. Every day, I run a cron job to create table and I insert records without using any trigger function. I insert records by calculating day of timestamp.

However, when I run a select query, query plan shows that every child table visited without checking constraints. Also I enabled constraints via "constraint_exclusion = on" in postgresql.conf

I think that the problem may be related to timestamp with timezone but I could not find any solution.

Thanks for your help, here are details

**Master table :**

```
CREATE TABLE points (
    point_key bytea,
    users_id integer,
    point_date timestamp with time zone
);
CREATE INDEX points_point_date ON points USING btree (point_date);
CREATE INDEX points_users_id ON points USING btree (users_id);
```

**Child table :**

```
CREATE TABLE points_20150701 (
    CONSTRAINT points_20150701_point_date_check CHECK (((point_date >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (point_date < '2015-07-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)))
)
INHERITS (points);
CREATE INDEX points_20150701_point_date ON points_20150701 USING btree (point_date);
CREATE INDEX points_20150701_users_id ON points_20150701 USING btree (users_id);
```

**Query that I perform :**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
            SELECT
                COUNT(point_key) as points
              FROM points
              WHERE users_id = 100 AND point_date >= '2015-08-25 00:00:00'::timestamp AND point_date <= '2015-08-31 23:59:59'::timestamp
```

**Result of the query :**

http://explain.depesz.com/s/VDI0

Comment: In your master table, you have `point_date` as a `timestamp with time zone`.  In your `CHECK` constraint, you have used `timestamp without time zone`.  Then, in your query, you just use `point_date >= '2015-08-25 00:00:00'::timestamp`, a `timestamp` type.  Make sure all the types are consistent, and then if that doesn't work, we'll dig a bit deeper.

Comment: I changed accordingly, but query plan did not change

Comment: I changed SELECT query to ::timestamp with time zone, the problem is now fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add my answer, which was correct in the comments, as the answer here.

## Be specific about your types!

In your master table, you have `point_date` as a `timestamp with time zone`.

In your `CHECK` constraint, you have used `timestamp without time zone`.

Then, in your query, you just use `point_date >= '2015-08-25 00:00:00'::timestamp`, thus using a `timestamp` type in your `WHERE` predicate.

To fix your problems, make sure that all of these entries are referring to a consistent type.  In your comments above, you indicated that you changed all entries to refer to the type `timestamp with time zone`, and that it fixed your issues.